# Software Design with multithreading and multiprocessing: My Example

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I am pretty new to multithreading and multiprocessing, however the main ideas I get. What I don't quite understand is, how can these concepts be applied together, for example having multiprocessing inside threads or having threads inside multiprocessing.

I am now trying to make my code as efficient as possible with multithreading and multiprocessing at the same time. At the moment I pretty much apply these concepts randomly and I am sure it actually makes things worse. Here is my problem statement. I try to achieve that the mentioned jobs run in shortest amount of time.

**Problem statement**
My actual code is much more fragmented into modules however for this purpose I think it's enough to work with the following skeleton of the main process.

```
class JobManager():
    def __init__(self):
        #some initializations of attributes:
        #threads, member attributes, sockets etc.
    
    def job1(self):
        #some quick calculations: no IO, no for loops
        
        #assume the most efficient computation takes 1min
    
    def job2(self):
        #some heavy calculations involving
        #a lot of data in memory and with high potential
        #for multiprocessing (for loops)
        
        #assume the most efficient computation takes 2min
    
    def job3(self):
        #retrieves some data via REST API and updates
        #in memory data
        
        #assume this takes 3min (can't be improved because
        #api has rate-limits)
    
    def job4(self):
        #opens a websocket, listens to
        #incoming messages and does some computations
        
        #this should run continuously in the background and update
        #in-memory data
    
    def job5(self):
        #opens another websocket to a different source,
        #listens to incoming messages and does some computations.
        
        #this should run continuously in the background and update
        #in-memory data
    
    def job6(self):
        #some quick calculations which for example depend on
        #job1, job2 to be finished

def run_threaded(job_func):
    job_thread = threading.Thread(target=job_func)
    job_thread.start()

def main():
    job_manager = JobManager()
    
    #start some possible threads (maybe for job4 and job5)
    job_manager.some_thread1.start()
    job_manager.some_thread2.start()
 
    scheduler = schedule.Scheduler()
    scheduler.every().hour.at("00:15").do(run_threaded, job_manager.job6)
    scheduler.every().hour.at("00:14").do(run_threaded, job_manager.job1)
    scheduler.every().hour.at("00:13").do(run_threaded, job_manager.job2)
    scheduler.every().hour.at("00:12").do(run_threaded, job_manager.job3)
    while True:
            scheduler.run_pending()
            time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

A requirement is that all the jobs are finished by some given time T, for example at 00:15 every hour. However the jobs might take unequal amount of time. Some of them can be run "concurrently or in parallel", but some need the result of the previous jobs.

How do I best apply multiprocessing and multithreading for this problem, possibly at the same time?

Cheers

Comment: Short question up front: Do you know the difference between threads and processes? Point is that your first paragraph already makes me wonder. Also, your question is pretty vague, "How to solve X with Y and Z?" is very unspecific and often an indicator of a lack of research.

Comment: Yes, I know the difference between threads and processes. I also know the guidelines, when to apply threads and when to apply processes. However, in my research I didn't come across examples where the two concepts are mixed. Also, I completely lack experience with that in terms of what is performing. For example above, I applied multiprocessing in job2 and wrapped that job into a thread, since I want multiple jobs to run concurrently. However, I am not sure if multiprocessing inside a child thread is even that efficient. That's what my question is targeting at.

Comment: Take a look at the source for [concurrent.Futures.ProcessPoolExecutor](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.11/Lib/concurrent/futures/process.py).